# How to use .htaccess to redirect this weird string : /%20rel=

Tags: .htaccess

I tried to make redirection of the following URL:

```
https://www.domain.tld/%20rel=
```

to

```
https://www.domain.tld/
```

But it seems to be more complicated than what I thought.

Here are some of the methods I used in my  `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^%20rel=$ /?&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^%20rel=$ /? [L,R=301]
Redirect 301 /%20rel= https://www.domain.tld/
```

and others, but non worked for me. Can someone help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\x20rel=/?$ / [L,R=301]
```

You need to use `\x20` to match `%20` or **in general** use `\xhh` to match any `%hh` character.